# Proposed edits with tables

Tags: bug, documentation

I was just going to review this [proposed edit](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/76839), and I went to side-by-side view, and BLARGLE!!!! What is this madness? The tables seem to overlap, at least in google chrome on linux. Here is an image:

[image]

Comment: Confirmed: Madness present in Chrome on Windows.

Comment: I saw this happen with another page, except it was the other column (so it wasn't blocking anything).